# Google Analytics tracking 1 character domain not working - Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, google-analytics

Is there any good solution to the well known issue where Google Analytics cannot track Internet Explorer visitors using IE 6-7 (maybe 8 too?) on a 1 character domain?

Please see my GA code below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXX-17']);
  _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'x.xx']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();
</script>
```

Comment: Looking at some of the available resources on the web that deal with this, the solution seems to be to set the domain name to `www.x.xx`, have you tried that?

Comment: Thanks. This domain has a lot of subdomains. I guess that solution will not work globaly? If not it should be possible to `_setDomainName` to subdomain.x.xx using PHP?